# NG Block UI in Angular 17

Tags: angular

Im trying to use NG Block UI in angular 17 and got this error [ng block ui error in angular 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtJV4.png)

Any idea of how this module works in angular 17?

Thanks in advance

I installed the module using npm i ng-block-ui, the docs says that BlockUIModule.forRoot() must be added to the imports of the 'app.module.ts' file but I don't the specified file in angular 17

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process for using `ng-block-ui`

1. Install ng-block-ui using `npm i ng-block-ui@next`, normal install was giving issues so I did this.
2. Then imports the modules and providers as seen in the below example, `importProvidersFrom(BlockUIModule.forRoot())` -> will fetch the providers needed at the global level
   `imports: [CommonModule, BlockUIModule],` -> will import the components etc. for the components.

Hopefully your will get resolved!

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BlockUIModule, BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, BlockUIModule],
  template: `
  <!-- Wrap app in block-ui component -->
<block-ui>
    <section class="hero">
        <h1>NG Block UI</h1>
        <p>Block UI Implementation for Angular 2 & Up</p>
        <iframe src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=kuuurt13&repo=ng-block-ui&type=star&size=large" frameborder="0" scrolling="0"
         width="75px" height="30px"></iframe>
    </section>
    <section class="block-form">
        <input class="control control__input" type="text" placeholder="Custom Message" #blockMessage />
        <button class="control control__btn" (click)="toggleBlocking(blockMessage.value)">
      Start Blocking
    </button>
    </section>
</block-ui>
  `,
  styleUrl: 'main.css'
})
export class App {
  // Wires up BlockUI instance
  @BlockUI() blockUI!: NgBlockUI;

  constructor() {}

  toggleBlocking(message?: string) {
    this.blockUI.start(message);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.blockUI.stop();
    }, 2500);
  }
}
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(BlockUIModule.forRoot())],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-onvr3w?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.css,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

[Reference stackblitz from angular 7](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-block-ui-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.css)